# Can I modify column cell text from a gridview based on a value from a column that isn't displayed in the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp gridview  that I want to change the color of text on cells based on  values from the column titled "Completed" from the database but I don't want that column to be included in the gridview.

I want three columns displayed in the gridview:
User|Form#|Department

If the form is marked as not completed in the database, the column cell for Form# text will be red.

I have this working right now by adding the column I don't want displayed in the gridview so it looks like this:
User|Form#|Department|Completed

In the SQLdatasource I have query:

```
Select User, Form, Dept, 
CASE Finished
WHEN 'True' THEN (' ')
WHEN 'False' THE ('!')
END AS Finished FROM Test1
```

In codebehind:

```
           if (Completed == "True")
            {
                cell3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
```

This works but I don't want the column titled Completed displayed in the gridview. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GridView TemplateFields instead of setting auto generated columns to true.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("User") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Form">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Form") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Dept") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Update

To check the values of the data bound to the GridView, use the `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a row
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check the value and set the backcolor
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["Finished"]) == true)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but it seems I run into an issue where I can't figure out how to get the value from codebehind because it's not in the gridview...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh that did it, I needed to add: if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["Finished"]) == true).   Thanks for the tip!