# how to change checkbox into yes or no value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have a column in dynamic gridview of data type bit.to run i'm getting in that column checkbox in my aspx page. how to change the checkbox into some style or font. using asp.net, c#

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvedition" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CssClass="table table-responsive"
                    OnRowDataBound="gvedition_RowDataBound">
```

in c# for gridview bind

```
protected void bindedition()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_edition_comparison", con);
                da.Fill(dt);
                gvedition.DataSource = dt;
                gvedition.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

but i got like this
[please click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI98g.png)

how to change the checkbox into some font.
i need to use fontawesome site icons how??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I modify column cell text from a gridview based on a value from a column that isn't displayed in the gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157119/can-i-modify-column-cell-text-from-a-gridview-based-on-a-value-from-a-column-tha)

Comment: not working @Vlam

Comment: please see my code what i do for next

Comment: you can give the css for this while adding checkbox in edit item template of grid in Html side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following procedure, it may help you.

1. As DataTable's column type can not be change then you need to clone the dataTable.
2. Change the Column Type for the respective Column you want to change.
3. Update the value in those column you wish to change based on your requirement.

   ```
   try
       {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                       new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                       new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)),
                       new DataColumn("Status",typeof(bool))
           });
           dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States", true);
           dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India", false);
           dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France", false);
           dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia", true);

           #region Cloned
           DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
           dtCloned.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(string);
           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
               dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
           }

           foreach (DataRow row in dtCloned.Rows)
           {
               row[3] = (row[3].ToString().ToLower() == "true") ? "Active" : "InActive";
           }
           #endregion

           GridView1.DataSource = dtCloned;
           GridView1.DataBind();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           throw;
       }
   ```